# How could use an account "rsync" created on LDAP server to scp files between linux servers

Tags: ssh, ldap, scp

I have a LDAP server which has an existing *rsync* account. I would like to use it to *scp* files among all of my servers. I added the public key of the *rsync* user to the */.ssh/authorized_keys* file and tried to *scp*. The error is as below:

```
[rsync@magdev2 fail2ban]$ scp jail.local rsync@abc.com:/tmp
The authenticity of host 'abc.com (10.104.0.24)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 5a:7e:d8:ce:58:8b:45:27:56:ac:b8:be:d2:a9:9e:33.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'abc.avery.com,10.104.0.24' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
[rsync@magdev2 fail2ban]$
```

Is there a way I can make this possible.

Comment: Is the home directory of your rsync user actually '/' as suggested by putting the public key in '/.ssh/authorized_keys'?

Answer (score 1):

`man ssh-keyscan`

> ssh-keyscan is a utility for gathering the public ssh host keys of a number of hosts.  It was designed to aid in building and verifying ssh_known_hosts files.  ssh-keyscan provides a minimal interface suitable for use by shell and perl scripts.